# Quickblox inconsistent API - no callback for subscriptionConfirm on Android

Tags: android, ios, quickblox

The quickblox API seems to be inconsistent between iOS and Android.

In iOS a user first makes a request to another like this:

```
addUserToContactListRequest(222)
```

The other user receives it in this callback:

```
chatDidReceiveContactAddRequestFromUser(111)
```

And sends back a confirm like this:

```
confirmAddContactRequest(111)
```

Which is received by this callback:

```
chatDidReceiveAcceptContactRequestFromUser(222)
```

However, in Android

I add by calling this:

```
chatRoster.subscribe(222)
```

Which is received in the callback:

```
new QBSubscriptionListener() {
    @Override
    public void subscriptionRequested(111) {

    }
}
```

And confirmed by:

```
chatRoster.confirmSubscription(111)
```

But how is this confirm processed? What is the callback?

I can't see it in the [documentation](https://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Guide:_Getting_Started_with_Chat_API).

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this here incase someone else is wondering.

You have to detect a "subscriptionRequestConfirmation" in a different more general listener; the rosterListener. This listener allows 4 overrides, we want to listen for entry updates (entryUpdated). If the entry is being updated to "both" that is a subscriptionRequestConfirmation message coming in. This achieves the equivalent to the one iOS callback function.

```
private QBRosterListener rosterListener = new QBRosterListener() {

    @Override
    public void entriesDeleted(Collection<Integer> userIds) {}

    @Override
    public void entriesAdded(Collection<Integer> userIds) {}

    private void subscriptionRequestConfirmed(int userID) {
         // do what you want to do
    }

    @Override
    public void entriesUpdated(Collection<Integer> userIds) {
         for (int userID : userIds) {
              if (chatRoster.getEntry(userID).getType() == RosterPacket.ItemType.both) {
                    subscriptionRequestConfirmed(userID);
              }
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void presenceChanged(QBPresence presence) {}
};
```

Horrible architecture.